# Compute the velocity vector.

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Can you solve explicitly? please. I don't know how to solve. Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @cruise yes I know matrix multiplication. But how to find velocity vector.

Comment: If $f(t) = A(t) x$, then $f'(t) = A'(t) x$ where $A'(t)$ is just the matrix obtained by taking the derivative of every term in the matrix entry-wise.

Comment: First do the matrix multiplication, and then take the derivative of the result.

Comment: @cruise is that all?

Comment: Yes, that's it :).

Comment: Thank you for help:) @cruise

Comment: No problem @B11  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin {bmatrix} -2x \sin 2 t - 2y \cos 2t \\2x \cos 2t -2y \sin 2t \end {bmatrix}$$ is the derivative @B11. You have to treat x and y as constants, and derivate with respect to t. Now you can fill in t = 0 to obtain:$$\begin {bmatrix} -2y \\2x \end {bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you:) I took its derivative wrong

Comment: No problem @B11 :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  If you multiply the matrices, you get $c_p(t)=\begin {bmatrix} x \cos 2 t - y \sin 2t \\x \sin 2t +y \cos 2t \end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} x \\ y \end {bmatrix}$.  Now take the derivative of each term and evaluate it at $t=0$

Added:  you have copied the matrix $c_p$, not taken the derivative.  You can take the derivative first if you want, but would get $c'_{p}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}-2\sin2t & -2\cos2t  \ \\2\cos2t &\ -2\sin2t \end{bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} x \\ y \end {bmatrix}$,  evaluate this at $t=0$, to get $c_p(0)=\begin {bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end {bmatrix}\begin {bmatrix} x \\ y \end {bmatrix}$then carry out the multiplication to get $c_p(0)=\begin {bmatrix} -2y \\ 2x \end {bmatrix}$ (The last two steps commute, but this order is easier).

Comment: $c'_{p}=\begin{bmatrix}cos2t \ -sin2t  \ \\sin2t \  \ cos2t \end{bmatrix}$ is this derivative ?

Comment: This is 2x2 matrix

Comment: @B11:  to make a matrix, you can put & signs between the columns.  The $\LaTeX$ will then figure the spacing for you.